# Bitcoin .11 Initial Blockchain Download Problem with OS X 10.10

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, synchronization, mac

I am loading the blockchain for a new wallet. Initially I had problems due to ISP issues. This issue is fixed and I now have 8 outbound connections working well with ping times ranging from 50-800 ms.

The problem is my blockchain is not reflecting the peer sync numbers. My ISP issues halted my blockchain download at 340401 blocks. Now this issue is resolved my debug window shows my peers have reached a sync height of 375167. The peers have been increasing for over a day now while my wallet has shown the same 340401 over this entire time period. I have closed and reopened the app multiple times to no avail. The wallet indicates it is "synchronizing with network" but the sync arrow in the right has not moved.

I have 12GB of memory. Bitcoin is currently using 4% of CPU. I am waiting to receive a payment but am stuck. Is anyone able to give me a clue as to why my peer block is not reflected in my blockchain? I am not a programmer and prefer a simple solution. Please help.